# How to use pooled results from multiple imputation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, mice

I've been reading some posts about data imputation using multiple imputation, specifically the MICE R package. I get the main idea of creating multiple datasets with imputed data. The part that is not clear to me is the linear regressions + pooling results. At the end I'd do something like this:

```
modelFit1 <- with(data,lm(var3~ var1+var2))
pool(modelFit1)
summary(pool(modelFit1))
```

The summary shows some coefficient estimates, should I use those to predict the final values for the missing data (var3)? If that's correct, what should I do if I also want to impute data for var2? Can I use var3 and var1 (kind of circular)?

Comment: The usual situation is like this: you want to fit a model, say a regression but you have missing data. So you impute them and use the imputed, completed datasets to fit the model. Because you did multiple imputations, you have to pool the regression results from all imputed datasets. This pooled result is an estimate of the regression model for the complete dataset with no missings. So at the step of fitting and pooling, all the imputation has already been done. I'm not aware of using the pooled results for further imputations.

Comment: Oh ok I got it. What if I just need to use the imputed data to calculate a mean across var1 var2 and var3? Should I average the n imputed datasets?

Comment: If you just want to estimate the univariate mean of var1, var2 and var3, you could use `with(data, lm(var1~1))` and then `pool` (the same for var2 and var3). Another possibility is to use the function `pool.scalar`. The help file of `pool.scalar` has an example of how to estimate the mean with the imputed datasets.

Comment: @COOLSerdash thanks for your help. Actually I want something like (var1 + var2 + var3) / 3, mean using the 3 variables where two of them had some missing values before imputation.

Comment: Adding the three variables and dividing by 3 gives you a new variable of length $n$ for each of the imputed datasets (basically a row-mean). Pooling comes into play when you calculate a statistic using this new variable, say the mean or variance.

Comment: I got it, but how would I pool them? would that be the mean of the row-means?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with this new variables (var1 + var2 + var3)/n.

Comment: If the new variable is called outcome, I'd like to use it to decide the best threshold (in the numeric outcome) and then create a binary classifier. In summary, I'd like to be able to visualize it and then take decisions based on the numeric value.
Should I just use one dataset and avoid all the issues?

Comment: One easy way to deal with your new derived variable "outcome" is to create the new variable before imputation, and impute it as just another variable, an approach known as JAV such that `data$outcome <- (data$var1 +  data$var2 +  data$var3 )/3` `JAVimp <- mice(data)`

Comment: @DerFluß is that statistically valid? I have 150 data points where 30 are missing for var1 and var2 (the same observations), var3 is complete and I want the mean of those three vars, should I just create beforehand the mean outcome and then imput those 30 missing means?